# Можно ли хостить один домен на нескольких хостинг площадках?

Tags: веб-программирование, dns, hosting

Задача следующая - нужно загрузить к примеру `1.jpg` с хостинга А и `2.jpg` с хостинга Б таким образом чтобы эти картинки были доступны с одного доменного имени - `mysite.com/1.jpg` и `mysite/2.jpg`.

Как это сделать и где можно почерпнуть больше инфы?

Comment: Делать переадресацию. Если нет файла в папке хостинга А, обращаемся к хостингу B и ищем там. Если и там нет, даём ошибку. Учтите, что это будет повышать нагрузку

Comment: На доменном имени в этом случае вешаем какой нибудь nginx, в настройках которго по имени файла опеределяем куда на самом деле надо обращаться и или проксируем запрос, т.е. отдаем его от этого ngix дальше и возвращаем ответ, либо выдаем клиенту redirect на какое то уникальное имя типа s1.mysite.com/... что бы клиент сам обратился

Comment: @Mike Я бы настроил nginx так, чтобы он сам ходил за файлами на бэкенд "другого" хостинга, а не пользователя посылал. В этом случае "прячется" инфраструктура за полноценным фронтэндом.

Answer (score 3):

Забавно, но в заголовке и в теле вы задали **два разных вопроса**.
И всё бы ничего, но **ответы на них тоже разные**.

> Можно ли хостить один домен на нескольких хостинг площадках?

**Да, можно.** Домен это имя, на которое система DNS-серверов возвращает IP-адрес сервера. DNS-серверы могут быть настроены возвращать **разные** IP-адреса для одного и того же доменного имени. Это запросто могут быть IP-адреса серверов на разных хостинг-площадках.

> нужно загрузить к примеру 1.jpg с хостинга А и 2.jpg с хостинга Б таким образом чтобы эти картинки были доступны с одного доменного имени

**Нет, так нельзя.** На этапе "разрешения домена" (domain name resolution) вы не можете передать никакой дополнительной информации о природе вашего запроса. Только доменное имя.

Кроме доменного имени DNS сервер получает от вас только ту информацию, что необходима для доставки вам ответа. К примеру, IP-адрес — его можно использовать, чтобы определить примерное местоположение и на основании этого выбрать сервер поближе к клиенту. Так работают CDN. Но кроме этого сложно придумать какие-то ещё применения.

DNS-сервер знать не знает, какой файл заправшивает пользователь, эта информация ему попросту не шлётся, т. к. это деталь для HTTP. А ответ DNS-сервера используется для многих HTTP-запросов.

---

Но всё не так плохо. **Ваша задача решаема**, просто не на уровне доменного имени. Должен быть сервер, который в зависимости от свойств запроса может передать его другому серверу на обработку, получить от него ответ и передать исходному клиенту. Такая роль сервера называется **обратный прокси**. Реализовать это можно целом рядом программных продуктов. Самый ходовой вариант: NginX, встречается HAProxy, возможны и другие варианты.